# What would cause myDivId.toggle() to work while myDivClass.toggle() does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, toggle

I have some DIVs that I am using JQuery to hide and show using the `toggle()` function. This has been working fine.

But I just recognized some relationships between some of these DIVs that would allow me to group some of them into a class.

I was hoping that this would allow me to toggle the DIV class instead of each of the DIV ids.

**So I want to do this:**

```
$("#myDIVId1").click(function ()
{
  $("myDIVClass").hide();
  $("#myToggle1").toggle();
});
```

**Instead of this:**

```
$("#myDIVId1").click(function ()
{
  $("#myToggle2").hide();
  $("#myToggle3").hide();
  $("#myToggle4").hide();
  $("#myToggle5").hide();
  $("#myToggle1").toggle();
});
```

But only this verbose ID access seems to work. Any ideas why?

Comment: I think you need to spend 5 minutes reading over the jQuery docs, based on your jQuery posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select the class, you need to put a '.'

```
$(".myDIVClass").hide();
```